# Can anyone help me with these minidumps?

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, bsod, windows-10-v1607, minidumps

Since the Windows 10 Anniversary update my WIFI keeps going into limited connectivity and loosing all networks at the same time. Disabling/enabling the card from device manager allows me to use it 5-20 minutes after rebooting. Every time I reboot it takes quite a long time before I get a BSOD with the error message DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE. These are 2 minidumps created after such BSODs. I've done 3 clean installs trying to sort this out as well as making sure all my drivers are up to date. Can anyone tell me what driver is causing this?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5p6ZeAlAcCAaWpad1lJZTBpR1k/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5p6ZeAlAcCAVFJNdGNqQm5yR0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There is a question with some basic steps, on how to use windbg, which should tell you which device driver is causing this problem.  Have you gone through those basic steps?

Comment: I haven't used windbg, I've checked it with osronline and bluescreenview, which as far as I understand don't provide the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Those tools while they can be used to identify the source of some problems, often point to the wrong file, when ti comes to problems like our having.  Which is the reason I suggested using the tool

Comment: Can you add those mini-dumps to your question? It would help with search engine indexing and help others in the future if you decide to remove them from your Google Drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [looking at the dump with Windbg](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows that the Intel Wifi driver `Netwbw02.sys` seams to cause the issue.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000004, The power transition timed out waiting to synchronize with the Pnp
    subsystem.
Arg2: 000000000000012c, Timeout in seconds.
Arg3: ffffa487b04e9040, The thread currently holding on to the Pnp lock.
Arg4: fffff800cb55d900, nt!TRIAGE_9F_PNP on Win7 and higher

Debugging Details:
------------------

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_4_Netwbw02_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_4_Netwbw02_IMAGE_pci.sys

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_4_Netwbw02_IMAGE_pci.sys
```

Look for a driver update and try to disable all power saving related settings in the device manager for the Wifi adapter.